# Database design for individual and group sign up

Tags: sql, database

I need to create a system that allows both individual users and groups (e.g., a company) to sign up for a subscription service.

The procedure for signing up for a group membership will involve a user paying for as many users as they require (e.g., 5) at sign up. Once they have paid they will be able to create these other users (i.e., have admin functions) that will be associated with this group (e.g., other members of their company). (They will be able to pay for more users for their group at a later date if they wish.) A user cannot be in more than one group. The original person that signed up on behalf of a group can assign admin roles to these newly created members.

For login purposes, I would like to have both individual users and group users in the same table of the database. For example, it could be called and have columns (to keep things simple):

user table:
user_id
username

I then thought that there must be a second table that shows the links between users (i.e., which belong to which group). Let's say that this is:

groups table:
group_id
user_id

I am guessing that this is a one-to-many relationship as many users can be in one group, but each user can be in only one group.

In order to assign the proper roles to the user that signed up on behalf of a group there would be another table called:

roles table:
role_id
user_id

This would allow some users to have permissions of admin rather than just user. I would then just have to lookup the user_id's of the admin role (a specific admin user_id) when they logged in and this would give them access to the correct people in their group.

Before I go ahead designing this database I was wondering if this is an appropriate database design to go about creating these individual and group users or if there is a better setup?

FURTHER INFO: There are two sign up forms: an individual sign up form and a groups sign up form.

For an individual, we will record their "username", their user_type (individual) and assign them a role of "user". They do not need to be assigned a group id and we will not need to convert their membership to a group membership later on.

For the user who signed up as a group using the group sign up form, we will record their "username", their user_type (group), no. of memberships purchased (e.g., 5), a group id (e.g., a unique integer) and assign them a role of "admin". Because they have purchased multiple memberships, they will be able to create/add new users to their group upto the number purchased. They can assign each new user a role of either "user" or "admin". A role of "user" in both individal and group membership has the same permissions, so there are only two types of role.

As such, I had planned a createUser() function that creates:

For an individual: username, user_type(individual), role(user)
For a group: username, user_type(group), group_id, no_purchased, role(admin)
For a new member of a group (created by admin): username, user_type(group), group_id(the same as the admin), role(admin or user)

I had then planned to create a checkUser() function that:

1. Gets their id, username, etc...
2. Checks if they are an admin or user.
3. If admin, then gets the users/admins that are in the same group as them.

Most calls to the database will be to login (i.e., username/password). I was looking to see what the simplest database structure would be for this situation.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent. I have kept the classes I will use in mind, but have not coded them yet. I know it is best to think what you are asking (querying) of the database when designing the database (i.e., do not think of database design in isolation). At the same time, I didn't want to go ahead with coding to a database with "shaky foundations". Hence, wanting to know if there is anything glaringly obviously wrong with the above setup. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like you might make your life simpler if you consider individual users as groups users with only one member.  This will also give you flexibility in the future if an individual user would like to expand into a group?

On the other hand you can keep it as you have it but I wouldn't bother specifying the user type.  That can be derived based on if they belong to a group or not.

Many ways to tackle this problem...

Comment: It seems that when I do this all I end up with is one table with columns: id, username, user_type, no_purchased, group, role. Then have NULL for no_purchased and group for individual users. Seems too simple!